# Castle Windsor WCF Facility host based only on a WCF service interface?

Tags: .net, wcf, castle-windsor

I have runtime provided WCF serrvice inteface :

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloService {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string message);
    }
```

What I'd like to do with my Windsor container (once for each provided service interface) :

```
container.Register(Component
    .For(typeof(IHelloService))
    .Interceptors(typeof(HelloServiceInterceptor)).First
    .ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel()
        .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint
            .BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding())
            .At("http://localhost:6080/HelloService/")
        )
    )
);
```

As you see, no implementation would be provided.

And the interceptor :

```
    class HelloServiceInterceptor: Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor {
        public void Intercept(Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInvocation invocation)
        {
            // Do what I must to answer the call
        }
    }
```

Is that possible with Windsor WCF Facility "as is"?
Is there some way to achieve this with Windsor WCF Facility "as is"?
Maybe I could provide a dummy implementation of the provided service interface, how would you do it?

Please, don't ask why ;)

If I get an answer elsewhere, I'll let you know.

Comment: Well, we're working on this @ Google Groups "Castle Project Users".  
I'll let you know when it comes to a solution :)

Comment: After looking deeper into this, and toying with solutions we developed, we decided to implement this feature, but not in v1.0. We'd need to make some changes in Windsor to support this for general case.